# Polymorphic Association Form - create new or edit existing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a polymorphic association set up for images on companies. I want to allow for up to 6 images to a company. If an image has already been created, that should display that image, if not, it should be an upload field.

Model set up:

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :images, as: :imageable
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :images
end
```

Controller set up:

```
def details
   images_count = @company.images.count
   build_number = 6 - images_count
   build_number.times { @company.images.build }
end
```

In the view:

```
<%= form_for(@company) do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :images,  multipart: true do |g| %>
      <%= g.file_field :image %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Is it possible to check to see if that particular instance of image is already created, and then display that image? As it is currently created, it will use the file_field for all 6 instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of your loop, you can check if the object is persisted

`<%= form_for(@company) do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :images,  multipart: true do |g| %>
      <% if g.object.persisted? %>
        --- DISPLAY IMAGE
      <% else %>
         <%= g.file_field :image %>
      <% end %>
   <% end %>
<% end %`

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked. 

I appreciate your help.